# Assigning a default value to a blank recalled database field

Tags: php, mysql, database, field

I'm working on an attempted social networking site with a relative of mine as a side project. I'm writing most of it bymyself. I have made it so each user is stored into a table with their data (mysql) and i want to do a single compare statement so that if a field is blank to change the recieved variable to "No data".

For example:
persons data is

```
name=john
age=34
mobile number=(empty because it hasnt been entered)
```

so when i receive the resource id with the mysql_func_assoc function
$result= mysql_query($sql);

```
$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$szUser_name=$db_field['user_name'];
$szAge=$db_field['user_age'];
$szNumber=$db_field['user_number'];
```

now i want an if statement to recognise a blank field (something like if($szUser=="" ||$szAge=="" ||$szNumber=="")) and then automatically change the respective field to "No data". i could just set all the values to ="No data" above and have them reassigned by the assoc function but im looking for a neat simple option. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you used smarty, it would be simple: `{$something|default:'No data'}`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe put this into a function so you can reuse the code?

```
function getField($fieldName, $fields, $default="No data") {
   return empty($fields[$fieldName]) ? $default : $fields[$fieldName];
}
```

So

```
$szNumber=$db_field['user_number'];
```

becomes

```
$szNumber=getField('user_number', $db_fields);
```

EDIT: Yeah you're right

//Nitpick :
Add an 's' to $db_field as well since it contains multiple fields. Or consider renaming it $db_row

Comment: thank you so much. i've seen code similar to this on some tutorial sites but wasn't sure how to implement it

Comment: just fiddling with this code atm, is that close parenthesis supposed to be on the end of the second line? im not trying to correct you, im just not sure what it is for

Answer (score 1):

**If your "empty" fields are actually set to `NULL`**:

For a pure MySQL solution you can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to achieve what you want assuming the "empty" fields are set to `NULL`. For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(`user_name`, 'No data') AS `username` FROM `users`
```

[`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) works in a similar way and is probably better suited to this particular job than `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`username`, 'No data') AS `username` FROM `users`
```

`COALESCE` can have many arguments and simply returns the first `NOT NULL` argument whereas `IFNULL` only accepts two arguments and it takes the first `NOT NULL` argument.

**If your "empty" fields are actually empty strings:**

If your values are empty strings rather than `NULL` then you can use:

```
SELECT IF('' = `username`, 'No data', `username`) AS `username` FROM `users`
```

For more information on the MySQL [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function [see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

**If you have a combination of both empty strings and `NULL`:**

You can use:

```
SELECT IF('' = `username` OR `username` IS NULL, 'No data', `username`) AS `username` FROM `users`
```

Comment: Just want to note that NULL != '' (empty string). And NULL isn't even equal to NULL, for the record. That's why I didn't suggest COALESCE, since OP said it was an "empty [column]".

Comment: Hence the line "Assuming the "empty" fields are set to `NULL`"

Comment: No worries. I have updated the original answer to make the distinction clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the kind of thing where you use the ternary operator :

```
$szNumber = (!empty($db_field['user_number'])) ? $db_field['user_number'] : 'No data';
```

Or, you can use the full if/else block.

You could also a CASE statement in your query :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_number = '' THEN 'No data' ELSE user_number END AS user_number
FROM yourtable
```

But it can make queries hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to choose MVC-based architecture for your application, transfer raw sql-data from controller into view, and to decide what data to output in view part. For example, Zend Framework allows to use classes called "view helpers", which will display "No data" instead of empty strings.

Comment: You do not need to implement the MVC pattern to accomplish this. In fact it has absolutely nothing to do with any design pattern.